# How to store n-dimensional vector in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, vector, word-embedding

I want to store a large `n`-dimensional vector (*e.g.* an [embedding vector](https://huggingface.co/blog/getting-started-with-embeddings)) in SQL Server as a piece of metadata associated with another row.

In this example, it will be a 384-dimensional vector, for example:

```
[0.161391481757164,   -0.23294533789157867, -0.5648667216300964,  -0.3210797905921936,  -0.03274689242243767,  0.011770576238632202, -0.06612513959407806,
-0.14662186801433563, -0.17081189155578613,  0.2879514992237091,  -0.1932784765958786,   0.009713868610560894, 0.23330552875995636,   0.03551964834332466,
-0.20526213943958282,  0.06445703655481339, -0.3146169185638428,   0.5788811445236206,   0.09118294715881348, -0.0048667509108781815,-0.16503077745437622,
 0.25162017345428467, -0.36395764350891113, -0.34742429852485657,  0.0526515394449234,   0.08912508934736252,  0.48464590311050415,  -0.04224267974495888,
 0.32445403933525085, -0.6847451329231262,  -0.20959551632404327, -0.027657458558678627, 0.20439794659614563,  0.6859520077705383,   -0.4988805055618286,
-0.26204171776771545, -0.18842612206935883,  0.07067661732435226,  0.02633148804306984,  0.03182782977819443,  0.28935596346855164,  -0.0016041728667914867,
 0.14609676599502563, -0.36272501945495605,  0.10288259387016296, -0.3651926815509796,  -0.3823530375957489,   0.14052163064479828,   0.006418740376830101,
 0.11741586774587631, -0.6509529948234558,  -0.15997739136219025, -0.42837604880332947,  0.12351743131875992,  0.0485026054084301,    0.24820692837238312,
 0.46972623467445374, -0.47954055666923523, -0.5238635540008545,  -0.3543052673339844,   0.22626525163650513,  0.18406584858894348,   0.6463921070098877,
 0.11894208937883377, -0.07143554836511612,  0.004256516695022583, 0.10088140517473221,  0.3335645794868469,   0.16905969381332397,   0.056856121867895126,
 0.11355260014533997,  0.3708053231239319,  -0.7484591603279114,   0.17503942549228668, -0.3249044418334961,   0.5901510715484619,    0.41506800055503845,
 0.05852462351322174,  0.5119204521179199,   0.2750142216682434,  -0.2058306783437729,   0.8199670314788818,   0.16698679327964783,  -0.1572146713733673,
 0.014733579009771347 ,0.0168467964977026,   0.4688740372657776,  -0.07839230448007584,  0.49326324462890625, -0.29934313893318176,   0.21525822579860687,
 0.1396997570991516,  -0.3420834243297577,  -0.5197309851646423,   0.10842061042785645, -0.0338996984064579,   0.35846689343452454,  -0.1660442352294922,
 0.15579357743263245,  0.015674782916903496,-0.8510578870773315,  -0.07501569390296936, -0.1791406124830246,   0.14926102757453918,  -0.2269722819328308,
 0.42619261145591736,  0.09489753842353821, -0.13341256976127625,  0.3312526345252991,   0.22534190118312836,  0.0679713636636734,    0.17042726278305054,
 0.14300595223903656, -0.06654901057481766, -0.2170567661523819,  -0.454984188079834,   -0.5516679286956787,  -0.10752955824136734,  -0.05743071809411049,
 0.32108309864997864, -0.5445901155471802,  -0.43162357807159424,  0.08207866549491882,  0.0664522647857666,   0.4478979706764221,    0.2190810590982437,
-0.05722910910844803, -0.0932786613702774,   0.01758035272359848,  0.16166797280311584,  0.44004616141319275, -0.21601708233356476,   0.43121641874313354,
 0.32022470235824585, -0.014045504853129387,-0.24948528409004211, -0.4389941990375519,   0.3816317319869995,  -0.5687862038612366,    0.1088542640209198,
-0.403241366147995,    0.08174201846122742,  0.21350793540477753,  0.2396722435951233,   0.4973253607749939,   0.31202447414398193,  -0.5260801315307617,
-0.3351263403892517,  -0.04100760444998741,  0.6609364151954651,  -0.2047063261270523,   0.19385716319084167, -0.5661329627037048,   -0.27058693766593933,
-0.1637117713689804,   0.30641692876815796, -0.08894442766904831, -0.052735116332769394,-0.13839660584926605, -0.6741533875465393,    0.05569711700081825,
-0.04354270175099373,  0.20251914858818054,  0.24813368916511536,  0.1719648838043213,   0.26782000064849854,  0.3137670159339905,    0.18599936366081238,
 0.23953016102313995,  0.17769533395767212,  0.46293920278549194, -0.19122551381587982, -0.5595004558563232,   0.09755659103393555,   0.3125424385070801,
-0.5813230276107788,  -1.0698442459106445,  -0.09045401215553284, -0.08948248624801636, -0.051830895245075226,-0.0001317809073952958,-0.08400193601846695,
 0.25725823640823364, -0.10135184973478317,  0.07884480804204941,  0.2091679722070694,   0.3950233459472656,   0.2745698094367981,   -0.872776448726654,
-0.16590780019760132,  0.4308463931083679,  -0.24375642836093903, -0.02120584435760975,  0.05213866010308266, -0.19898287951946259,  -0.5506985187530518,
 0.40167248249053955,  0.1640072464942932,  -0.010167916305363178, 0.14038121700286865,  0.4958030879497528,  -0.7259818315505981,   -0.24387206137180328,
 0.08528701961040497,  0.03415993973612785, -0.16687284409999847,  0.3804749548435211,  -0.08561687171459198, -0.2752263844013214,    0.5883951783180237,
-0.3283255994319916,  -0.12724250555038452,  0.08751262724399567, -0.44206979870796204, -0.11079336702823639, -0.16302113234996796,   0.11022322624921799,
-0.09404750168323517, -0.256179541349411,    0.20473307371139526,  0.41829538345336914, -0.1095203086733818,   0.02342342585325241,  -0.18814104795455933,
-0.2540932893753052,   0.48397907614707947,  0.03593514859676361, -0.089835524559021,   -0.6478171944618225,  -0.1757517009973526,    0.0672023594379425,
 0.0695127546787262,  -0.6398074626922607,  -0.03958022966980934, -0.10351496934890747,  0.22433893382549286,  0.6756673455238342,   -0.2924160957336426,
 0.17503827810287476,  0.12915058434009552, -0.239552840590477,    0.15498916804790497, -0.4730042815208435,  -0.12289212644100189,  -0.004052990116178989,
 0.11593572050333023, -0.1965983510017395,   0.5210273265838623,  -0.18184830248355865,  0.2579534947872162,  -0.1920309066772461,   -0.389960378408432,
 0.04139290377497673, -0.11638019979000092, -0.10620912909507751, -0.5321099162101746,   0.13135096430778503, -0.07761876285076141,  -0.0830138698220253,
-0.01572849042713642,  0.31080499291419983, -0.41445496678352356,  0.1609737128019333,   0.5787453651428223,  -0.05459209159016609,   0.1318219006061554,
-0.06957206130027771,  0.15152350068092346, -0.07094550132751465, -0.196294367313385,    0.12644843757152557,  0.23419199883937836,   0.5845456719398499,
-0.19989481568336487, -0.19607964158058167, -0.19692276418209076, -0.08633144199848175, -0.004551170393824577, 0.09362921118736267,  -0.14167727530002594,
-0.14917594194412231,  0.31781134009361267,  0.18779256939888,     0.42154577374458313, -0.20578211545944214,  0.14142100512981415,  -0.5664211511611938,
 0.18177354335784912,  0.14776530861854553,  0.29254236817359924,  0.17831481993198395, -0.1894354224205017,  -0.2836195230484009,   -0.4065170884132385,
-0.14325398206710815,  0.17800962924957275,  0.7763587832450867,   0.5497004389762878,  -0.00946379080414772, -0.48568078875541687,  -0.022227048873901367,
-0.005903944373130798, 0.4351034462451935,   0.05010621249675751, -0.12799566984176636, -0.06675072759389877,  0.167253315448761,    -0.1653994619846344,
 0.21004730463027954,  0.2765181362628937,   0.5885812640190125,  -0.326379656791687,   -0.007390940561890602, 0.27159956097602844,  -0.043763305991888046,
-0.39229199290275574, -0.19412016868591309,  0.4250912666320801,   0.6105153560638428,  -0.06168382614850998, -0.5341082811355591,   -0.611929714679718,
 0.08125612139701843, -0.1779184639453888,   0.5319408774375916,  -0.23601730167865753,  0.22285249829292297, -0.32505497336387634,   0.2152460366487503,
 0.4679816663265228,   0.048206135630607605,-0.24099768698215485, -0.30208054184913635,  0.13667792081832886,  0.3552468717098236,   -0.12280546128749847,
-0.006191314198076725,-0.10851636528968811,  0.08330328017473221, -0.09545236080884933, -0.02249046228826046,  0.0003346469602547586,-0.12273653596639633,
-0.05594412609934807,  0.027804357931017876,-0.4045255482196808,  -0.18987023830413818, -0.0027474926318973303,0.30244430899620056,   0.2323288917541504,
-0.2729185223579407,   0.12836921215057373,  0.27967774868011475,  0.3031359016895294,   0.41273725032806396, -0.06173351779580116,   0.33845168352127075,
 0.26775869727134705, -0.2933143079280853,  -0.0485006645321846,   0.11777450144290924,  0.6205862760543823,  -0.07637807726860046,  -0.19466432929039001,
-0.3994691073894501,   0.15689416229724884, -0.11139731854200363, -0.2333720475435257,   0.2364773154258728,   0.30898618698120117,  -0.1263875812292099,
-0.231489360332489,    0.34536853432655334,  0.6001318097114563,  -0.44741731882095337,  0.07382357120513916, -0.019649405032396317, -0.1029537245631218,
 0.369470477104187,   -0.032077688723802567,-0.13972929120063782,  0.24549521505832672, -0.13091856241226196, -0.029257331043481827]
```

### Attempt#1 - n-dimensional vector → n-columns

My first thought was to store the 384 `real` values in a separate table, with a key to the original row (vertical partitioning):

```
CREATE TABLE Embeddings (
   RowGUID uniquedientifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   f1 real NOT NULL, 
   f2 real NOT NULL,
   f3 real NOT NULL,
   f4 real NOT NULL,
   f5 real NOT NULL,
   f6 real NOT NULL,
   f7 real NOT NULL,
   f8 real NOT NULL,
   f9 real NOT NULL,
   f10 real NOT NULL,
   ...snip...
   f384 real NOT NULL)
```

| RowGUID | f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 | f5 | f6 | f7 | ... | f384 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6ba7b814-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8 | 0.161391481757164 | -0.23294533789157867 | -0.5648667216300964 | -0.3210797905921936 | -0.03274689242243767 | 0.011770576238632202 | -0.06612513959407806 | ... | -0.029257331043481827 |

This...sorta...works. But it is unwieldy. Plus, my vectors today *happen* to be 385-dimensional; but they may soon be [1556-dimensional](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/what-are-embeddings), which exceeds the SQL Server maximum of [1,024 columns per table.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

### Attempt#2 - n-dimensional → n-IEEE 32-bit floats → varbinary(n*4)

The next idea was to pack the 4-byte (32-bit) floats into a `varbinary` column:

```
CREATE TABLE Embeddings (
   RowGUID uniquedientifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   PackedVector varbinary(1516) NOT NULL -- 384 floats * 4 bytes = 1540 bytes
)
```

```
0x0000000100000002000000030000000400000005000000060000000700000008...0000017F
  \______/\______/\______/\______/\______/\______/\______/\______/   \______/
     f1      f2      f3      f4      f5      f6      f7      f8        f384
```

And then when it comes time to read each `Single`, use `SUBSTRING` to rip the 4-byte float out of the varbinary, and then convert it to a `real`:

```
DECLARE @f1 real = CAST(SUBSTRING(PackedVector, 0*4, 4) AS real);
```

Except two down-sides:

- **Downside#1**: You cannot convert a [`binary(4)` to a `real`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) (even though you can convert a `real` to a `binary(4)`; just not the other way:

  [image]

  May be able to workarond it with `decimal` or `numeric`).
- **Downside#2**: The math of computing the euclidian distance between two vectors is conceptually valid:

  ```
  DECLARE @target VARBINARY(1536) -- packed 384-dimensional vector

  SELECT TOP(10) RowGUID, SUM(POWER(CAST(SUBSTRING(Embedding, i*4+1, 4) AS real) - CAST(SUBSTRING(@target, i*4 + 1, 4) AS real), 2)) as distance
  FROM Embeddings
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (0), (1), (2), ..., (383)) AS sequence(i) -- Fill in the values from 0 to 383
  GROUP BY RowGUID
  ORDER BY distance ASC
  ```

  But that will be pretty poorly performing (even if issue #1 didn't exist).

### Attempt 3 - Do what Joe Celko does

Many years ago, someone on the Microsoft newsgroups had [the same question](https://microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming.narkive.com/G679BC53/best-way-to-store-vectors#post1):

> Can anyone point me to a reference or discuss the best way to store a
> vector of 120 to 480 numbers in the database? Rows seem to be out
> since we would quickly top the billion row mark. A table with 480
> columns is too unnormalized. A single varchar(max) column? This
> seems the best answer for now unless there is a more efficiant way of
> storing it.
>
> Thanks for any help or opinions,

And then **--CELKO--** responded:

> I think of a vector as a particular kind of mathematical structure and
> you seem to be talking about a list of some kind. Vectors have a fixed
> number of dimensions, etc. Here is a guess:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE Vectors (
>    vector_id CHAR(3) NOT NULL, --whatever
>    dim_nbr   INTEGER NOT NULL,
>    CHECK (dim_nbr BETWEEN 1 AND 480),
>    PRIMARY KEY (vector_id, dim_nbr),
>    dim_val   INTEGER NOT NULL
> );
> ```

Making the values of a the vector into rows:

**Embeddings**

| RowGUID | dimNumber | dimValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6ba7b814-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8 | 1 | 0.161391481757164 |
| 6ba7b814-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8 | 2 | -0.23294533789157867 |
| 6ba7b814-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8 | 3 | -0.5648667216300964 |
| 6ba7b814-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8 | 4 | -0.3210797905921936 |
| 6ba7b814-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8 | 5 | -0.03274689242243767 |
| 6ba7b814-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8 | 6 | 0.011770576238632202 |
| 6ba7b814-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8 | 7 | -0.06612513959407806 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 6ba7b814-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8 | 384 | -0.029257331043481827 |

This is **probably** the best approach.

### Nothing better?

Doesn't SQL Server has better support for vectors? I know there is GEOSPATIAL/GEOGRAPHY types, but i gather those only work for 2-dimensional vectors (e.g. lattuitude+logitude)? Can't they be [abused to solve the problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622964/12597)

And since the goal is to compute euclidian distance between two vectors, is there a data structure that does a better job of allowing math? (varchar? xml? json? varbinary? variant?)

## Bonus Reading

- [Indexing N-dimensional vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58719399/indexing-n-dimensional-vectors)
- microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming: [Best way to store vectors?](https://microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming.narkive.com/G679BC53/best-way-to-store-vectors)
- [Getting Started With Embeddings](https://huggingface.co/blog/getting-started-with-embeddings)
- [How to customize LLMs like ChatGPT with your own data and documents](https://bdtechtalks.com/2023/05/01/customize-chatgpt-llm-embeddings/)
- FAISS - Facebook open-source vector database: https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss
- Pinecone, an online vector database system: https://www.pinecone.io/
- Microsoft: [What is a Vector Database?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/semantic-kernel/concepts-ai/vectordb) (https://archive.ph/15kXF)
- SQLServerCentral: [The Rise of Vector Databases](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/editorials/the-rise-of-vector-databases)
- [Optimized approach for calculating cosine similarity in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68161189/optimized-approach-for-calculating-cosine-similarity-in-sql-server) *(tips for using cosine angle distane)*

Comment: `geography` goes up to 4 dimensions I think, but that won't help you. Sounds like you need an SQLCLR type, but you can't use them in Azure though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also try something like explained [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/vector-similarity-search-with-azure-sql-database-and-openai/)

> There is no specific data type available to store a vector in Azure SQL database, but we can use some human ingenuity to realize that a vector is just a list of numbers. As a result, we can store a vector in a table very easily by creating a column to contain vector data. One row per vector element. We can then use a columnstore index to efficiently store and search for vectors.

So create a table to hold the vectors:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[embeddings]
(
    [article_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [vector_value_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [vector_value] [float] NOT NULL
)
```

And then we can use T-SQL to efficiently compute distances:

> On that table we can create a column store index to efficiently store and search for vectors. Then it is just a matter of calculating the distance between vectors to find the closest. Thanks to the internal optimization of the columnstore (that uses SIMD AVX-512 instructions to speed up vector operations) the distance calculation is extremely fast.
>
> The most common distance is the cosine similarity, which can be calculated quite easily in SQL.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(a.value * b.value) / (  
        SQRT(SUM(a.value * a.value)) * SQRT(SUM(b.value * b.value))   
    ) AS cosine_similarity
FROM
    vectors_values
```

The SQL query is calculating the cosine similarity between two vectors, represented by the columns `a.value` and `b.value`. Cosine similarity is defined as follows:

[image: LaTeX]

Where:

- [image: LaTeX] is the dot product of vectors [image: a] and [image: asdf]
- (|A|) and (|B|) are the magnitudes of vectors (A) and (B), respectively

The important parts of the query are:

1. `SUM(a.value * b.value)`: Calculates the dot product of vectors (A) and (B).
2. `SQRT(SUM(a.value * a.value))`: Calculates the magnitude of vector (A).
3. `SQRT(SUM(b.value * b.value))`: Calculates the magnitude of vector (B).

Finally, the entire expression divides the dot product by the product of the magnitudes to find the cosine similarity, which is returned as `cosine_similarity`.

Answer (score 1):

The real advantage of vector databases (I work for Weaviate fwiw) is that it allows ANN-based vector indices to be built. Vector searches are computationally very expensive, and vector DBs allow searches that are orders magnitudes faster than say, brute-force searches through a Numpy array or something.

I would definitely not advise saving vectors into SQL if you want to do any kind of similarity-based retrieval, which is probably why you have vectors in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved exactly the same task using plain json text as a vector store.

I used openjson() to convert it to a table on the fly.

I created a function to build a binary search index from a set of vectors, and a function to search vectors in a given vicinity of a vector using binary index.

These simple steps turn SQL Server in vector database.

See [vector-database](https://github.com/nesterovsky-bros/vector-database).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try MyScale DB, which is a SQL-based vector database.